# how to using Preg_match for array (multiple key)?

Tags: php, arrays, string

for example, i have these few keywords

```php
$word = "word1,word2,word3";
```

and substract/explode that using `$keyword = explode(",", trim($word));`
then ill get these `$keyword[0]` `$keyword[1]` and `$keyword[2]`

now, how to match these keyword using preg_match?

```php
$others = "this is example where there is word1"; 

if(preg_match('/($keyword[0]|$keyword[1]|$keyword[2])/i', $others)){
echo "matched";
}
```

the problem is, if there is only 2 words, it will matched all the words in `$others`.

is there any more propper or easier and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you need to initialize the regex from an array? Try `$rx = '/' . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {
    return preg_quote(trim($i), "/");
}, explode(",", $word))) .  '/i';`, then use `preg_match($rx, $others)`, see [demo](https://3v4l.org/dFuNt). Add word boundaries, `\b`, on both ends to only match whole words. Or, better, `(?<!\w)` at the start and `(?!\w)` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) along with [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$word = "word1,word2,word3";

$others = "this is example where there is word1"; 


$wordsArray = explode(',',$word);
$othersArray = explode(' ',$others);
if(count(array_intersect($othersArray,$wordsArray)) > 0){
    echo "matched";
}else{
    echo "not matched";
}
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/2fiTm  And https://3v4l.org/vIrnh

if you want case insensitive check then use `strtolower()`:

```
$wordsArray = explode(',',strtolower($word));
$othersArray = explode(' ',strtolower($others));
if(count(array_intersect($othersArray,$wordsArray)) > 0){

    echo "matched";
}else{
    echo "not matched";
}
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/tgflb

Note:- I assume that text(`$others` variable) words are separated with white space.

Comment: so the $othersArray explode every words? does it takes a long time if the $others has a long sentence? i mean if the $others is long, does is it affect the server?

Comment: nope. it needs to be too-too-too-too-too...........  long to affect server speed. you can check it here:- https://3v4l.org/t4XUG/perf#output